# This data sheet for this 20x4 lcd module

Tags: lcd

Here's my old code for a 16x2 lcd. (I'm aware this is irrelevent but I just wanted to point out what I need help with)

```
define FunctionSet 0x3B
define DisplayOn 0x0E
define EntryModeSet 0x06
define ClearScreen 0x01
define SecondLine 0xC0
define thirdline 0x??
define fourthline 0x??
define reset cursor 0x??
```

If one of you would be so kind, could you determine the hex values I would need for these functions with the 20x4 module.

[The Datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/32387.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find those values in the datasheet (but didn't look very carefully).

If this module uses the standard address style:
SecondLine: 0x40
ThirdLine: 0x14
FourthLine: 0x54

ResetCursor: 0x02

http://web.alfredstate.edu/weimandn/lcd/lcd_addressing/lcd_addressing_index.html
http://mil.ufl.edu/4744/docs/lcdmanual/commands.html